# Razor Pages routing only working with one parameter, not two

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages web site that shows groceries. There is an area called Shop, which contains a Razor page named Product.cshtml. This page does not have any routing set in it, just the plain `@page` directive with nothing else on the line.

The `OnGet` method in the page has several parameters, including two string parameters named `category` and `section`...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string currentFilter,
                                       string section,
                                       string category,
                                       string searchAreaID,
                                       string so, int ps, int p = 1)
```

If I browse to `/Shop/Product?category=Bakery` or `/Shop/Product?category=Bakery&section=Bread` all works fine.

What I would like to do is to use URLs like `/Shop/Product/Bakery` and `/Shop/Product/Bakery/Bread` instead.

I added routes in `Startup.cs` as follows...

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
  options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Shop", "/Product", "/Shop/Product/{category}/{section}");
  options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Shop", "/Product", "/Shop/Product/{category}");
  // other routes set here (none relating to the above)
})
```

This allows me to browse using the URLs I showed above, but when I use tag helpers to generate links, the URLs don't always come out correctly. For example, I have the following markup that generates a parent/child set of `<ul>`s, which are marked up with CSS (omitted for clarity)...

```
<ul>
  @foreach (Category category in Model.Categories) {
    <li>
      <a asp-area="Shop"
         asp-page="/Product" 
         asp-route-category="@category.Name">@category.Name</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            @foreach (Section sub in category.Sections) {
              <li><a asp-area="Shop"
                 asp-page="/Product"
                 asp-route-category="@category.Name" 
                 asp-route-section="@sub.Name">@sub.Name</a></li>
            }
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  }
</ul>
```

The URLs in the top-level links are correct, being of the form `/Shop/Product/Bakery`, but the links in the second-level do not use the section name in the routing, but rather add them in the querystring, such as `/Shop/Product/Bakery?section=Bread`

Anyone any idea what I've done wrong here? Please let me know if there is anything else I need to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the page route like this:

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Shop", "/Product", "/Shop/Product/{category?}/{section?}");
});
```

**The generate url**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's still producing URLs like `/Shop/Product/Bakery?section=Bread` instead of `/Shop/Product/Bakery/Bread`

Comment: Have you deleted this line `options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Shop", "/Product", "/Shop/Product/{category}");`. It can work only with the above configuration. You can see my screenshot.

Comment: No I didn't. I thought that it looked at routes in order, and matched the first one it found, so the second wouldn't be used if the first matched. Taking the second line out worked, but I'm still not sure why. Please could you add a little more explanation in your answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks again

Comment: Hi @AvrohomYisroel, yes, it is in order, but the order is reverse. It first look at the last one, if not match, then look upside. You can add another route at the bottom `options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Shop", "/Product", "/Shop/Product");` then the two route parameters all become querystring.